# Mongoose - Best way to update a record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update a record with mongoose. I've seen other answers on SO. but they are very old like 4 - 5 years ago.

What is the best way to update a record with mongoose ? both for `PUT` and `PATCH` requests.

Currently I'm doing it like so. but I don't think this is a good way for models with many fields.

```
export const updateTestimonial = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const values = await testimonialSchema.validateAsync(req.body);

  const testimonial = await Testimonial.findById(req.params.id);

  if (!testimonial) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Testimonial not found' });
  }

  testimonial.name = values.name;
  testimonial.text = values.text;

  const updatedTestimonial = await testimonial.save();

  res.status(200).json(updatedTestimonial);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findByIdAndUpdate`

```
export const updateTestimonial = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const values = await testimonialSchema.validateAsync(req.body);
  const testimonial = await Testimonial.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, values, {new : true});

  if (!testimonial) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Testimonial not found' });
  }

  res.status(200).json(testimonial);
});
```